# Error while running the emulator in android studio : Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation

Tags: android-studio

In android studio I'm getting this error while opening the emulator : Emulator: emulator: `ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation.`

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the version of AS you have.
This issue is usually related to Graphics emulation on the AVD.
Try this:
Goto Tools->AVD Manager.
Then click on the the edit icon:
[image: AVD Edit]

Now click on the "show advance setting" and scroll down.

[image]

You should see there a Graphics combo box.
Change the value from "Automatic" to "Software".
Tell me how it goes.